# L'ancien français « pite, pitet » : Comment ces mots ont-ils evolués pour signifier « la misère » ?

Tags: anglais, étymologie, latin, évolution

> [pity (n.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=pity&allowed_in_frame=0) [⟸] early 13c., from Old French ***pite, pitet*** "pity, mercy, compassion, care, tenderness; **pitiful state, wretched condition"** (11c., Modern French *pitié*), from Latin *pietatem* (nominative *pietas*) "piety, loyalty, duty" (see piety). Replaced Old English *mildheortness*, literally "mild-heartness," itself a loan-translation of Latin *misericordia*. English *pity* and *piety* were not fully distinguished until 17c. **Transferred sense of "grounds or cause for pity" is from late 14c.**

Au sujet du nom latin (au nominatif, du 3e déclinaison) *pietās*, les entrées sur [Lewis & Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=pietatem&la=latin#Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=pietas1-contents) et [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pietas#Latin) impliquent l'absence des sens de « pitiful state, wretched condition » en latin. Donc, il semble que ces 2 sens en gras aient apparu en ancien français. Pourtant, la ressemblance de ces 2 sens avec les « grounds or cause for pity », contredit la dernière phrase ci-dessus en gras, qui prétend que ces 2 sens sont apparus en anglais, au 14<sup>e</sup> siècle.

Comment interpréter cette étymologie pour comprendre comment les sauts sémantiques se sont écartés du sens original en latin ?

Comment rapprocher les acceptions ultérieures (figurées) des acceptions originales en latin?

Comment: http://languagelore.net/2012/06/pity-and-its-lexical-congeners/ m'a aidé.

Answer (score 3):

[***Piété***](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/pi%C3%A9t%C3%A9) et [***Pitié***](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/piti%C3%A9) ont la même origine, et cela laisse des traces dans leur histoire.

---

*Piété*

**A. − Vx. Synon. de *pitié***

B
1. Attachement fervent à Dieu; respect des croyances et des devoirs de la religion
2. Sentiment de respect pour les dieux, pour les pratiques de leur culte.
3. P. méton. Expression, manifestation relative à la piété.

C. − Sentiments humains alliant l'affection au respect.
1. Amour respectueux des enfants pour les parents.
2. Respect envers les morts.
3. Attachement à la patrie, à certaines abstractions.

*Utilisation récente* :
 Ac. **1694** et 1718: pieté; dep. 1740: piété.

---

*Pitié*

1. Sentiment d'affliction que l'on éprouve pour les maux et les souffrances d'autrui, et qui porte à les (voir) soulager; disposition à éprouver ce sentiment. Synon. apitoiement, commisération, compassion, miséricorde;

*Suit une longue énumération des locutions utilisant* pitié *et des sens dérivés*.

**Étymol. et Hist.**

1. Ca **1050** pietét « sentiment de compassion ».
2. 1666 regarder en pitié « considérer avec du mépris mêlé d'une vague compassion ».

Du lat. pietas proprement « *piété* (envers les dieux, les parents) », « sentiment du devoir» (dér. de pius « pieux [sens sacré et profane] »), qui a évolué pour signifier dès l'époque impériale « clémence, sentiment de bonté miséricordieuse (de l'empereur) », d'où « sentiment de compassion » dans la langue des Chrétiens et « bonté, charité ».

---

À la seconde question :

> Comment rapprocher les acceptions ultérieures (figurées) des acceptions originales en latin ?

La réponse est dans les dates d'apparition, pour la première question :

> Comment interpréter cette étymologie pour comprendre comment les sauts sémantiques se sont écartés du sens original en latin ?

Le début de réponse est aux § C de *piété* et 1. de *pitié*, auxquels fait écho l'étymologie commune.