# Pour ne pas laisser croire à de la pitié ou à du désir

Tags: articles

*Paris-Briançon* de Philippe Besson :

> Alexis est tenté d'approcher sa main de la tête baissée, de la tête
> vaincue, de glisser ses doigts dans la chevelure blonde mais il s'en
> empêche pour ne pas laisser croire à **de** **la** pitié ou à **du**
> désir.

Serait-il possible d'utiliser l'article défini dans cette phrase ? La pitié et le désir seraient alors des concepts.

> Alexis est tenté d'approcher sa main de la tête baissée, de la tête
> vaincue, de glisser ses doigts dans la chevelure blonde mais il s'en
> empêche pour ne pas laisser croire à **la** pitié ou **au** désir.

Je pense que oui, mais j'ai des doutes.

Comment: Il me semble que la raison tient au fait que l'auteur pensait à "avoir de la pitié et avoir du désir" et l'a raccourci. Assez astucieux, à mon avis.

Comment: @Lambie La raison de quoi ? Quelle phrase aurait été raccourcie ? Pourquoi remplaces-tu *ou* par *et* ?

Comment: Vraiment, tu ne comprends pas ce que j'a dit?? La raison pour laquelle l'auteur a écrit "de la pitié" et "du désir", c'est parce qu'il pensait à "avoir de la pitié et avoir du désir".

Comment: @Lambie C'est vrai, je ne comprends pas ce que tu cherches à dire. La phrase n'a rien d'astucieux ou de raccourci. C'est simplement du français normal alors qu'au contraire, *pour ne pas laisser croire avoir de la pitié ou avoir du désir* ou je ne sais quelle autre forme avec *avoir* aurait été terriblement lourd.

Comment: @jlliagre Alors, je vais essayer de le dire autrement. Il ne s'agit pas d'insérer "avoir de la pitié et avoir du désir" dans la phrase. Il s'agit du fait qu'en français on dit : avoir **de la pitié** [pour quelqu'un]. Et **non pas** *avoir pitié de quelqu'un*. "Raccourci" *dans ce sens-là*. A partir de la langue. A la différence, p. ex. de l'espagnol oú l'on dirait tener pena de alguien.

Comment: On mais dit aussi: avoir de la pitié pour (v. trans.)
1.témoigner de la compassion pour quelqu'un, avoir de la pitié. http://dictionnaire.sensagent.leparisien.fr/AVOIR%20DE%20LA%20PITIE%20POUR/fr-fr/

Comment: @Lambie On peut bien dire *avoir pitié* ou *avoir de la pitié*, donc je ne vois toujours pas d'astuce. Sinon, hors-sujet, mais la [pitié](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/14407/1109), ce n'est pas que la peine. *Tengo piedad de èl.*

Comment: I pity you is Tengo pena de ti, everyday language. No one goes around saying in everyday language tengo piedad de ti. L'astuce c'est que pour éviter le concept (concept comme Oreste dit). ou une généralité (comme tu dis), il existe bien dans la langue une autre forme, qui le permet. Je ne fais qu'appuyer ce que toi et Oreste disent, parbleu !. Je sais ce que tu vas me dire: oh, mais tu ne connais pas le sens du mot astuce. Et voilà, on repartira sur le ruban de Möbius....

Comment: @Lambie Oui, tu as raison. C'est ton utilisation du mot astuce qui est étrange alors qu'il n'y a rien d'astucieux dans la phrase en question. Qu'un auteur francophone utilise une expression naturelle en français n'a rien qui sorte de l'ordinaire.

Answer (score 3):

Non, il n'est pas vraiment possible de remplacer l'article partitif par l'article défini ici sans que la phrase ne laisse une impression d'inachevé.

Comment: :( Pourquoi la pitié et le désir ne pourraient pas être un concept ici ?

Comment: Parce que dans ce cas, *croire à la pitié ou au désir* signifierait *croire à la pitié ou au désir en général*, sans qu'il y ait de lien évident avec les doigts dans les cheveux.

Comment: Oui, c'est vrai.