# « Ne pas laisser croire (à) » ?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, locutions, transitivité

Dans une autre [question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/50232) on a présenté l'extrait suivant :

> Alexis est tenté d'approcher sa main de la tête baissée, de la tête
> vaincue, de glisser ses doigts dans la chevelure blonde mais il s'en
> empêche pour ne pas laisser croire **à** de la pitié ou **à** du désir.
> (*Paris-Briançon*, Philippe Besson)

Je pensais en comprendre le sens et ça se lit aisément, mais à force de regarder la phrase j'en suis venu à me demander pourquoi on y trouve la préposition *à*. Le verbe [*laisser*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/laisser/1) peut certainement avoir une fonction de semi-auxiliaire et [*croire*](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/rdp/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_catlog_c&page=9XTI2Y9I40AA.html#zz9XTI2Y9I40AA) peut certainement être transitif indirect, donc avec *à*, entre autres, mais [*laisser croire*](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9L0132) est aussi une locution signifiant *insinuer, laisser comprendre sans le dire nettement*, tel *laisser entendre* (Ac.), mais ça se construit avec une objet direct (*...une chose*) ; sauf que je ne peux imaginer la phrase sans la préposition alors qu'avec *laisser paraître* (*montrer, découvrir* (Ac.)), oui.

- Peut-on expliquer pourquoi on trouve la préposition *à* ici ; de quel
  emploi de *laisser* et de *croire* s'agit-il ici ; quel sens en
  résulte et comment se distingue-t-il de celui de la locution (insinuer, laisser comprendre sans le dire nettement) ?
- Peut-on se passer de la préposition ici ?

Answer (score 3):

Le sens est :

> Il s'en empêche pour ne pas qu'on puisse imaginer qu'il s'agisse de pitié ou de désir.

Laisser croire : Permettre à d'autres de croire.

L'expression est courante:

> *Le taux d'abstention à la mi-journée peut **laisser croire à** une victoire facile d'Emmanuel Macron face à Marine Le Pen. Mais beaucoup dépend du comportement de l'électorat Mélenchon. On fait le point.* [Watson](https://www.watson.ch/fr/amp/!660547085), 24/04/2022

La préposition est indispensable. *Pour ne pas laisser croire de la pitié* ou *laisser croire une victoire* n'auraient pas de sens.

Comment: "laisser croire à" implique permettre à *d'autres* de croire? X aurait pu **me laisser croire à** une histoire sans fin.

Comment: @Lambie Dans la phrase en question, il n'y a pas de ***me*** et en mettre un n'aurait pas de sens.

Comment: Oui, d'accord. Je pensais que tu voulais dire en général. J'ai du mal à comprendre pourquoi un locuteur natif pose la question.

Comment: @Lambie Qu'est-ce qui a motivé ton commentaire, *autre* ou le pluriel ?